# javascript: pulse text using fade in and fade out?

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to get a piece of text to fade in and out automatically without a click or hover method.

i'm not sure i can use an on page load function either because the text i want to fade in and out only appears after a user clicks to open another div on the page.? (I may be wrong?)

I am using this script but the text is static and not doing anything. Can anyone advise me where i'm going wrong? Thanks

```
<script>
function cycle() {
    $('#morebutton-pics').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#morebutton-pics').fadeIn(1000);
        cycle();
    });
}
$(document).click(function(){
    cycle();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please include the relevant `html`

Comment: Or, more important, show us the code that lets the text "*appear after a user clicks to open another div on the page*". Likely this is your error, as your polling solution does not work. Triggering the animation on show would be the better choice anyway.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like it would be better as a CSS animation:

```
#morebutton-pics {
  animation: pulse 1s alternate infinite;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  from {opacity:1}
  to {opacity:0}
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {opacity:1}
  to {opacity:0}
}
```

This will work in Firefox, Chrome and IE10. Since this is more eye-candy than a required feature, that seems acceptable to me.

Comment: Great answer, way better and lighter than the javascript way :)

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding that CSS is probably the better answer, your code doesn't work because it repeatedly calls `cycle()` without ever waiting for the second animation to finish.

```
function cycle() {
    var $el = $('#morebutton-pics');

    $el.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $el.fadeIn(1000, cycle);  // loop in the second callback
    });
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak: No, he uses `cylcle` in the outer callback. That will produce an infinite animation chain over time (double length of what is executed), but not a stack overflow or the like.

Comment: @Bergi agreed - apart from DOM ready issues I can't see why the given function wouldn't work at least in part, although it's definitely not "correct".

Comment: @Alnitak: If `#morebutton-pics` does not exist, the loop will time out. I guess he creates that element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$(document).click(function(){
     cycle();
});
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {cycle(); });
```

if the div is hidden it does not matters

Comment: incorrect - `.ready()` requires a function reference, not the _result_ of calling `cycle()`.

Comment: now it's correct, but instead of downvoting you can correct it (the key "edit" is for that)

Comment: I only correct answers where the poster has demonstrated clue.  Your answer still doesn't resolve the OP's bug in the `cycle` function.  It could also just be written `$(document).ready(cycle)` without the additional function wrapper.